# How to extract BundleResources files (.asset extension)

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, assets

What should I do if i want to extract this .asset game file? I think this is the asset file of the game, but I can't open it with utinnyripper or Asset Bundle Extractor.

[File download](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/pedujmftvngri/BundleResources)

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]